# Manipulate syntax error: Table::nliter

Tags: manipulate, evaluation, warning-messages, hold

`Manipulate[Table[Orange, n], {n, 1, 5, 1}]` works well, but `Manipulate @@ {Table[Orange, n], {n, 1, 5, 1}}` raise `Table::nliter` error. So, why?

Comment: `{Table[Orange, n], {n, 1, 5, 1}}` evaluates before `Apply[]` (`@@`) acts on it, and `Table[Orange, n]` will throw said error. Try `Manipulate @@ Hold[Table[Orange, n], {n, 1, 5, 1}]`. (Pretty sure this is a dupe.)

Comment: @J.M. Great help, thanks!

Comment: @J.M. could not find any better, looks good enough, does it not?